# Remove object from Arraylist If it equals userinput and else print out something only once

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, remove-if

I have been trying most things now but it doesn't seem to work. I want to remove a specific object from an Arraylist if the user enters a specific name. And if not I want the program to print "Can't find dog". I have a getName and toString method in my other class that is working well with all the other options i have in this program, this is the only thing that is not working.

Case 4 is where the removal is supposed to happen. But I also want you to look at Case 3 to compare that Case 3 prints out "can't find dog" no matter what, and case 4 prints out "Cant find dog" as many times as there are objects.

Here is the main method:

```
ArrayList<Dog> doglist = new ArrayList<Dog>();
Scanner myscan = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean running = true;

while (running) {
    System.out.println("\n************************************");
    System.out.println("\nVälkommen till Kennelklubben!");
    System.out.println("\n************************************");
    System.out.println("\n[1] Register new dog");
    System.out.println("[2] Print out list");
    System.out.println("[3] Increase age");
    System.out.println("[4] Remove dog");
    System.out.println("[5] Quit program");
    System.out.println("\n************************************");
    System.out.println("\nChoose: ");

    int option = myscan.nextInt();

    switch (option) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Write name:");
            String name = myscan.next();
            System.out.println("Write race:");
            String race = myscan.next();
            System.out.println("Age:");
            int age = myscan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Weight:");
            double weight = myscan.nextDouble();

            Dog dog = new Dog(name, race, age, weight);

            doglist.add(dog);

            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Minimum length of tail:");
            double userInput1 = myscan.nextDouble();

            for (Dog d : doglist) {
                if (d.getTailLength() >= userInput1) {
                    System.out.println(d.toString());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Can't find dog");
                }
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Name of dog:");
            String userInput2 = myscan.next();

            for (Dog d : doglist) {
                if (d.getName().equals(userInput2)) {
                    d.increaseAge();
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Can't find dog");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Name of dog:");
            String userInput3 = myscan.next();
            for (Dog d : doglist) {
                if (d.getName().equals(userInput3)) {
                    doglist.remove(d.toString());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Can't find dog");
                }
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            running = false;//Avslutar loopen och därmed programmet
            System.out.println("Programmet avslutat");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Nu blev det fel, välj mellan [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]");//Felmeddelande om valet är någon annan siffra än de som menyn innehåller
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is the other class with my methods

```
public class Dog
{
    private String name;
    private String race;
    private int age;
    private double weight;
    private double tailLength;

    public Dog (String name, String race, int age, double weight)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.setRace(race);
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;

        if(race.equals("tax"))
        {
            this.setTailLength(3.7);
        }
        else
        {
            this.setTailLength((age - weight) / 10);
        }
    }


    public String getRace()
    {
        return race;
    }

    public void setRace(String race)
    {
        this.race = race;
    }

    public double getTailLength()
    {
        return tailLength;
    }

    public void setTailLength(double tailLength)
    {
        this.tailLength = tailLength;
    }

    public int increaseAge()
    {
        age++;
        return age;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name + " " + getRace() +
                " " + age + " " + "år" + " " + weight + " " + "kg" + " " + getTailLength();
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are on your way to encounter a nasty exception called [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). This happens when you are iterating over a list and try to remove an item from the list at the same time

Comment: you can't remove by name in case 4

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple dogs with the same name in that list?

Comment: @smac89 Ok i see, but how would i do this if i want to remove the object by name?

Comment: @smac89 it is possible, but we can assume that it is not for now, if that makes things easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity's sake, here's what you currently have:

```
            System.out.println("Name of dog:");
            String userInput3 = myscan.next();

            for(Dog d : doglist) 
            {
                if(d.getName().equals(userInput3)) 
                {
                    doglist.remove(d.toString());
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Can't find dog");
                }
            }

            break;
```

`dogList` is a `ArrayList<Dog>`.

`ArrayList.remove()`'s [documentation states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)):

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is unchanged.

Here, you're calling `remove()` with the parameter `d.toString()`. `d` is the instance of Dog that you want to remove. `d.toString()` returns a `String`.

So `dogList.remove(d.toString())` will attempt to remove the `String` from the list. Obviously this `String` is not in the list as it is a list of `Dog`. This `String` will not be found and nothing will be removed.

As the documentation says, you need to pass the instance that you want to remove. You would need to call `doglist.remove(d)`. This however will cause an error since you can't remove items from a list while you are iterating on it.

Thus, you need to store the `Dog` instance in a temporary variable and remove it after you have iterated on it.

Something like this would work:

```
Dog dogToRemove = null;
for (Dog d: dogList) {
    if (d.getName().equals(userInput3)) {
        dogToRemove = d;
    }
}

if (dogToRemove == null) {
    System.out.println("Could not find dog with name " + userInput3);
} else {
    dogList.remove(dogToRemove);
}
```

**Note that there are other ways to do this**, this is just one of them. I encourage you to find alternatives so you understand how this works better.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This works and I think I get it now, but I will look more into things like this, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For case 3 :

- Try to add an else and put in your message there

  ```
          System.out.println("Name of dog:");
          String userInput2 = myscan.next();

          for (Dog d : doglist) {
              if (d.getName().equals(userInput2)) {
                  d.increaseAge();
                  break;
              }
              else {
                  System.out.println("Can't find dog");
              }
          }

          break;
  ```

For case 4 : You can remove by Index

```
System.out.println("Name of dog:");
            String userInput3 = myscan.next();
            for (Dog d : doglist) {
                if (d.getName().equals(userInput3)) {
                    doglist.remove(doglist.indexOf(d));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Can't find dog");
                }
            }
            break;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still prints out "can't find dog" even when it finds the dog and increases the age?

Comment: It prints out "can't find dog"  one time ?

Comment: yes exactly :)  Prints it out one time no matter what

Comment: Are you sure that you did remove the Sysout outside the loop ?

Comment: It works now, it wasn't the sysout but just a small error on my part, thx for the help :)

Comment: can you explain more to help you ?

Comment: for(Dog d : doglist) 
         {
             if(d.getName().equals(userInput2)) 
             {
                 d.increaseAge();
                 break;
             }
             else
             {
              System.out.println("Can't find dog with     name:" + userInput2);
             }
         
         }
     
     
     break;

Comment: What happens is that when it can't find the name, it prints out "can't find dog" 3 times if there are 3 objects. And when it finds the dog, it still prints it out 1 time?

Comment: Try this code  :
`case 3:
    System.out.println("Name of dog:");
    String userInput2 = myscan.next();
int flag = 0;
for(Dog d : doglist)
 { if(d.getName().equals(userInput2))
  { d.increaseAge();
    flag = 1;
    break; }
 } 
 
if (flag == 0){
 System.out.println("Can't find dog with name:" + userInput2);
}

break;`

Comment: You're welcome , if it works you can vote up to make it visible for other users .

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do this with Java 8.

```
doglist = doglist.stream().filter(dog -> !dog.getName().equals(userInput3)).collect(toList());
```

One line of code, easily readable, and no moving parts

And if you want a message if the dog is not found then:

```
if (doglist.stream().anyMatch(dog -> dog.getName().equals(userInput3)){
  doglist = doglist.stream().filter(dog -> !dog.getName().equals(userInput3)).collect(toList());
} else {
   System.out.println("Can't find dog");
}
```

Comment: Nice one liner, but if you can add a way to still determine if the dog was found or not, that would complete this answer

Comment: edited to add if statement with output when dog not found